# Async.js says my callback is being called twice

Tags: javascript, async.js

I'm using async.js to manage some parallel loading. When I call this function the first time, all is well. When I call it the second, async gets mad that my callback (highlighted) is called a second time, as if it's the same callback. What's going on here?

```
initialize: function (complete){
    //complete any initial setup work required for the page here

    //crashAjax.loadthis, loadthat
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            templateHandler.onLoad(moduleSection, function () {
                callback();
            });
            templateHandler.load(moduleSection, templates);
        },
        function(callback){
            users = ajax.getUsersForDepartment();
            callback(); <-"Uncaught Error: Callback was already called."
        }
    ],
    // optional callback
    function(err, results){
        complete();
    });


},
```

Thanks!